# htaccess redirects are confusing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link like this:

`http://www.example.com/blog/something/article-name/`

I want to re-write it to:

`http://www.example.com/article-name/`

the "something" is variable so I can't just use `RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/something/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1`

I've searched every article I could find with various htaccess redirects and none applied to my scenerio, that is 1 fixed folder (blog) and 1 variable folder (something -- could be anything).  I've tried this and it doesn't work either:

`RedirectMatch ^/blog/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$2`

.... just gives me the same thing minus blog.

Please help!

Comment: It's confusing to you because you are trying to pull a variable out of thin air. Take this URL `http://www.example.com/article-name/` Where is the something in that URL? The server can't possibly know there is a variable without you telling it there is. If `something` is dynamic, you will not be able to use `http://www.example.com/article-name/` and have that as your URL in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, because you refer to rewriting and redirecting. In the case of rewriting, Panama Jack is right. If you are looking for the shorter URI for the purposes of **rewriting**, the server cannot simply guess the `something` part.

However, if you are trying to **redirect** (say, you have changed your CMS, for example), then you can use the following. The `mod_rewrite` rule below will redirect `/blog/variable/article` to `/article` with a 302 temporary redirect.

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2 [R=302,L]
```

If you would like to make the redirect permanent and cached by your browser, change `302` to `301`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wish I could upvote this a thousand times.  This is really what I wanted and it works perfectly.  Thank you!